# Replace values in data frame with other values according to a rule

Tags: r, dictionary, dataframe

I am an beginner in R and don`t find a solution for the following problem. Any help would be really appreciated!

I have a data.frame and want to replace certain values of a column with defined other values.

data.frame

```
date<-c("19921231","19931231","19941231","19941231","19931231","19941231")
variable<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
value<-c(1:6)
dataframe <- data.frame(date,variable,value)
```

attempt to solve problem

```
yearend<-c("19921231","19931231","19941231")
year<-c("1992","1993","1994")
map = setNames(yearend,year)
dataframe[] = map[dataframe]
```

error message

```
Error in map[dataframe] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

The problem is obviously, that it is not a matrix. What is the most efficient way  to solve this problem? It should also work if I want to replace "real" character, e.g. "BGSFDS" with "BASF stock".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A nice function is `mapvalues()` from the plyr package:

```
require(plyr)
dataframe$newdate <- mapvalues(dataframe$date, 
          from=c("19921231","19931231","19941231"), 
          to=c("1992","1993","1994"))
```

Comment: This has been the answer that I was looking for!

Comment: Why was this answer not at the top

Answer (score 3):

merge() might also be of help.

```
yearend<-c("19921231","19931231","19941231")
year<-c("1992","1993","1994")
map = data.frame(yearend,year)

merge(dataframe,map,by.x='date',by.y='yearend')
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to extract the year from the date, you can do this with the following line of code:

```
dataframe$year <- substr(dataframe$date,1,4)
```

When you want assign a class to the new variable simulataniously:

```
dataframe$year <- as.integer(substr(dataframe$date,1,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match`:

```
dataframe <- transform(dataframe, Year = year[match(date, yearend)])

      date variable value Year
1 19921231        a     1 1992
2 19931231        a     2 1993
3 19941231        a     3 1994
4 19941231        b     4 1994
5 19931231        b     5 1993
6 19941231        b     6 1994
```