# Search multiple columns for a given selection of values and thier associated lables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with 12 columns, the following data frame is a simplified example.

```
    ID <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)                                   
    period<- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)                            
    column1<- c(100, 400, 500, 300, 700, 800, 300, 100, 1100, 100)      
    column2<- c(1500, 100,800,900,100,1100,1200,200,100,400)            
    column3<- c(200, 1000, 200,NA,500,800,1100,300,100,2000)                    
    df<- data.frame(ID, period, column1, column2, column3) 

ID period column1 column2 column3
1      1     100    1500     200
1      2     400     100    1000
2      1     500     800     200
2      2     300     900      NA
3      1     700     100     500
3      2     800    1100     800
4      1     300    1200    1100
4      2     100     200     300
5      1    1100     100     100
5      2     100     400    2000
```

1) I am intressted in the values 100, 200 and 300 and I want to add a new column (column 4) that contains 1 if these values are available in column1 to column3 or 0 if these values are not available.

2) If these values (100, 200, 300) are available, I want to lookup for names that belong to these values from the lookup_table.

```
agent_number<- c(100, 200, 300)
agent_name<- c("agent1", "agent2", "agent3")
lookup_table<- data.frame(agent_number, agent_name)
```

This is the output what I would like to have.

```
ID period column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7
 1      1     100    1500     200       1  agent1  agent2    <NA>
 1      2     400     100    1000       1  agent1    <NA>    <NA>
 2      1     500     800     200       1  agent2    <NA>    <NA>
 2      2     300     900      NA       0  agent3    <NA>    <NA>
 3      1     700     100     500       1  agent1    <NA>    <NA>
 3      2     800    1100     800       0    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
 4      1     300    1200    1100       1  agent3    <NA>    <NA>
 4      2     100     200     300       1  agent1  agent2  agent3
 5      1    1100     100     100       1  agent1  agent1    <NA>
 5      2     100     400    2000       1  agent1    <NA>    <NA>
```

For question 1, I have tried this, but did not work.

```
agent_number<- c("100", "200", "300")
df %>% select(ID, column1:column3) %>%
mutate_at(vars(column1:column3),list(~ ifelse(. == agent_number, 1, 0)))
```

For question 2, I have used left_join for each of the 12 columns in my orginal data frame, but could not change the names of column1 to 12 after merging the tables. I got each time the same output as below.

```
left_join(df, lookup_table, by=c("column1"="agent_number"), suffix = c("", ".1"), suffixes_mandatory = c(FALSE, TRUE))
left_join(df, lookup_table, by=c("column2"="agent_number"), suffix = c("", ".2"), suffixes_mandatory = c(FALSE, TRUE))
ID period column1 column2 column3 agent_name
 1      1     100    1500     200       <NA>
 1      2     400     100    1000       <NA>
 2      1     500     800     200       <NA>
 2      2     300     900      NA       <NA>
 3      1     700     100     500       <NA>
 3      2     800    1100     800       <NA>
 4      1     300    1200    1100       <NA>
 4      2     100     200     300       <NA>
 5      1    1100     100     100       <NA>
 5      2     100     400    2000       <NA>
```

I have large data files and I am looking for a code that does not work very slow.
Thank you so much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.table solution:

```
# Convert your dataframe to a data.table with setDT
setDT(df)

# Initiate column to all zeros
df$column4 <- 0
# Where column1, column2, or column3 is in 100,200,300
df[column1 %in% c(100,200,300) | 
   column2 %in% c(100,200,300) | 
   column3 %in% c(100,200,300), 
   column4 := 1]

# Begin to map values
df$column5 <- NA
df$column6 <- NA
df$column7 <- NA

# Map values solution from 
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565949/replace-values-in-data-frame-with-other-values-according-to-a-rule
require(plyr)
df$column5 <- mapvalues(df$column1, 
          from=c(100,200,300), 
          to=c("agent1","agent2","agent3"))
df$column6 <- mapvalues(df$column2, 
          from=c(100,200,300), 
          to=c("agent1","agent2","agent3"))
df$column7 <- mapvalues(df$column3, 
          from=c(100,200,300), 
          to=c("agent1","agent2","agent3"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a large lookup table with more codes than  only 100, 200 and 300. Therefore, I prefer the join/merge function, but I don't know how to  use the suffix  in left join to rename the new columns.