# map values of a data frame to another in R, possibly without plyr

Tags: r, replace, mapping

I have two data frames, `df` and `counties`. I would like to replace the coordinates that are in columns 3 and afterward column of `df` with the column `fips` in the `counties` data frame.

```
df = 
year            location       location_NN_1      location_NN_2      location_NN_3
2076 43.59375_-116.78125  41.15625_-90.65625  41.21875_-90.65625 41.15625_-90.65625
2077 43.59375_-116.78125  43.34375_-78.15625  43.34375_-78.21875 43.28125_-78.15625
2078 43.59375_-116.78125  41.34375_-90.78125  41.21875_-90.65625 41.53125_-73.96875
2079 43.59375_-116.78125  43.53125_-116.78125 41.34375_-90.78125               <NA>
2080 43.59375_-116.78125                <NA>               <NA>                <NA>

counties = 
fips   location
36073  43.34375_-78.15625
17161  41.34375_-90.78125
```

I expect the output to look like:

```
output 
year            location       location_NN_1      location_NN_2      location_NN_3
2076 43.59375_-116.78125               17131             so_on             so_on
2077 43.59375_-116.78125               36073             so_on             so_on
2078 43.59375_-116.78125               17161             so_on             so_on
2079 43.59375_-116.78125      so_on, so_forth            so_on               <NA>
2080 43.59375_-116.78125                <NA>               <NA>              <NA>
```

Perhaps something like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565949/replace-values-in-data-frame-with-other-values-according-to-a-rule) would work. Which I do not want to use, since it uses `plyr`, and I do not have good experience with `plyr`. Loading it messes up other libraries.

any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: The `so_on` means not matching?

Comment: no, it means the `counties` data frame includes proper fips, but I did not want to copy all the data here.

Comment: ok, so I am not sure if this works or not as some of the values are not filled e.g. `17131` not in example `df[3:5] <- lapply(df[3:5], function(x) counties$fips[match(x, counties$location)])`

Comment: you are officially manager of R section of stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can select the columns of interest, loop through the columns with `lapply`, `match` with the 'location' column of 'counties' to get the numeric index of matches, then based on that get the corresponding 'fips' values, and update the dataset columns (`[]`)

```
df[3:5] <- lapply(df[3:5], function(x) counties$fips[match(x, counties$location)])
```